# Python: How to use loops with a txt file with 2 types of inputs

Tags: python, loops, input

I need to write a program that has a list of names and below each set of names (in 2 lines) are 2 sets of numbers by a comma (1,2)

So something like this

```
Jane
Doe
14.5,12.3
```

Which is repeated with the same 3 lines until the loop gets to 0,0, which is what terminates the loop.

How do I exactly write a loop with simultaneous inputs, and how to i seperate between string and the numbers.

Comment: Where specifically are you getting stuck - what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to distinguish between the 3 inputs by count but that hasn't been working so far. I'm just stuck at the beginning, I don't know how to write a loop with different types of inputs.

Comment: There is an important thing I forgot to mention, the last 3 lines of the input list are as followed:

##### \n ##### \n 0,0

which would mean these are the termination lines I guess

Comment: which shouldn't matter if `0,0` occurs before then...

Answer (score 1):

If the items are grouped over three lines, I'd use:

```
data = []
with open('inputfile.txt') as inf:
    numbers = None
    while numbers != [0, 0]:
        name1 = next(inf).strip()
        name2 = next(inf).strip()
        numbers = [float(n) for n in next(inf).split(',')]
        data.append((name1, name2, numbers))
```

This uses the input file as an iterable, getting 3 lines at a time until `numbers` becomes equal to `[0, 0]`.

Comment: You need to compare numbers to a list (which `map` produces), not a tuple

Comment: @Ivo: indeed, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

One first step that might make sense would be cutting your list down to just the names and numbers you need. You can do that easily enough because you're only interested in the part of the list that comes before the first line with '0,0': you can just take the index of that line and slice the list there to get that section:

```
your_data = ['Jane', 'Doe', '14.5,12.3', etc etc]
z_index = your_data.index('0,0')
new_data = your_data[:z_index + 1] # +1 to include '0,0' as the last element
```

From there it depends on what you want to actually do with the data. But let's say you want a list of dictionaries with the names and numbers:

```
results = []
while new_data:
    results.append({'first':new_data[0],
                    'last':new_data[1],
                    'numbers':new_data[2]})
    new_data = new_data[3:]
```

The number pairs are still strings here, since it was read from your txt file. You can split the numbers and convert them to floats when you assign them to the dict, if you need to.

Also, I'm making a few assumptions here: that your list will always have the line '0,0', and that there's no chance it'll be missing any of the first/last/number lines. If those aren't always the case, you'll need a bit of logic to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

My take on it using `takewhile` and a custom function using `ast.literal_eval`, along with the `grouper` recipe from `itertools` and then transpose it a bit after, eg:

```
from itertools import takewhile, izip_longest
from ast import literal_eval

def until_0(text):
    try:
        return literal_eval(text) != (0, 0)
    except ValueError:
        return True

with open('/home/jon/data.txt') as fin:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
    data = list(takewhile(until_0, lines))

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

print [list(el) for el in grouper(3, data, fillvalue='0,0')]
# [['Jane', 'Doe', '14.5,12.3'], ['Jane', 'Doe', '6.7,2.3'], ['John', 'Doe', '0,0']]
```